# Using an expression - How to group individual days into a month and calculate a total?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

Is there a way to group days along with their dollar amounts into a combined monthly total automatically?  I'm generating a report that pulls in data from our core system, so instead of manually creating the sum or group, I want Excel or Access to do it for me - there will not be a set number of lines per month.

For example, my report lists a line item by date for each cost center along with a dollar amount:

```
Date      cost center   description     amount
5/18/17    101          deposit          12.50
5/18/17    102          deposit          12.50
5/19/17    101          deposit          12.50
5/19/17    102          deposit          12.50
```

I need it to group the days into the month and have a grand total of the amounts.  So in this case for the month of May the total deposits is $50 (cost center is irrelevant).

Comment: Would Pivot Tables work?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Month() formula you can create a column containing only the month and them create a Pivot Table that will summarize months for you.

I've created a sample for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka4zyy6o0hqd54h/Using%20an%20expression%20-%20How%20to%20group%20individual%20days%20into%20a%20month%20and%20calculate%20a%20total.xlsx?dl=0).